# Delete Line Breaks in Excel worksheet from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I want to open an excel file via vb.net and delete all line breaks of a choosen worksheet. What I tried to do is:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class MyExcel
    Private _xlsheetRelevant As Excel.Worksheet
    Private _xlApp As Excel.Application
    Private _xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Public Shared _shxlworkbook As Excel.Workbook

Public Sub New()
    Try
        _xlApp = CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    Catch e As Exception
        _xlApp = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    End Try
    _xlApp.Visible = True
End Sub

Public Sub OpenFile(ByVal FilenameL As String)
    _xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilenameL, ReadOnly:=False)
    _xlworkbook = DirectCast(_xlApp.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
    _shxlworkbook = _xlworkbook
    _xlApp.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveLinebreaks()
    _xlsheetRelevant = DirectCast(_xlworkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1"), Excel.Worksheet)
    _xlsheetRelevant.Cells.Replace(What:=Chr(10), Replacement:="", LookAt:=2, SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ExcelV As New MyExcel
        ExcelV.OpenFile("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Mappe1.xlsx")
        ExcelV.RemoveLinebreaks()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I always get the following Message:

> Microsoft Excel cannot find any data to replace. Check if your search
>   formatting and criteria are defined correctly. If you are sure that
>   matching data exists in this workbook, it may be on a protected sheet.
>   Excel cannot replace data on a protected worksheet.

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution by myself:

```
_xlsheetRelevant.Cells.WrapText = False
```

instead of

```
_xlsheetRelevant.Cells.Replace(What:=Chr(10), Replacement:="", LookAt:=2, SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False)
```

Comment: This means that there is no line break in your strings. What you are doing is removing the automatic word wrap.

Comment: Oh ok. But let's say I create a Line Break with Alt+ENTER (this is a Chr(10)) and I run the code above, there is no line break anymore. Doesnt that mean, that wraptext delete the Chr(10) too. Btw. the replace chr(10) doenst work at all for me. Only What:= imputvalue that run through was """ & Chr(10) & """ The Chr(10) was substituted with the Replacement-Value but there was still a wrap.

Answer (score 0):

By default Excel will try to proceed to the replacement of the whole string, in your case you
need to replace only some characters :

```
_xlsheetActive.Cells.Replace(What:=Chr(10), Replacement:="", LookAt:=2, SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Hi pmartin! It is still not working. I edited my post and provide all the code. Should work with a from and a standard button. Would be aweseome if you could give me any kind of hint.